# Loop AsyncTask to fetch JSON and store as object in same list

Tags: java, android, json, object, android-asynctask

I want to read and store all `JSON` values from [this api Link](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/Mini/0) with `get request` *"Mini"* as example (which is actually an user input variable) and the last number is the page your are viewing. Every page can hold a max of 50 results. The [same link is also in XML](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/xml/item-search/Mini/0) format (I must read and store as JSON, this is for easier understanding)

In this exmaple there are 8 pages with a total of 359 results. I need to loop through all pages and add all the JSON values to the same object list.

I have the code which work to read one page. I do not know how to make it loop through all pages and add to same object list.

In the acitivty.java onCreate I call the AsyncTask.

```
String userSearchRequest = search_activity_data.getString("userSearchRequest");
int page = 0;
String spidy_iTN_url = "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/" + userSearchRequest + "/" + page;

itemsByInput_AsyncTask itemsByInput_AsyncTask = new itemsByInput_AsyncTask();
itemsByInput_AsyncTask.setItemListToListings(this);
itemsByInput_AsyncTask.execute(spidy_iTN_url);
```

This is my AsyncTask class called `itemsByInput_AsyncTask.java`

```
import constructors.itemResults_api_constr;
import constructors.itemRoot_api_constr;

public class itemsByInput_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        JSONObject Jo_result;
        private itemListToListings itemListToListings;

     public void setItemListToListings (itemListToListings itemListToListings) {
        this.itemListToListings = itemListToListings;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        return spidyHttpGetRequest(params[0]);
    }

    public JSONObject spidyHttpGetRequest(String URL){
        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            Jo_result = new JSONObject(result);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Jo_result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
        this.itemListToListings.itemListToListings(JoToJO_constructor(jsonObject));
    }


    public itemRoot_api_constr JoToJO_constructor(JSONObject Jo_result) {
        itemRoot_api_constr spidy_iTN_rootO = new itemRoot_api_constr();

        try {
            spidy_iTN_rootO.setCount(Jo_result.getInt("count"));
            spidy_iTN_rootO.setPage(Jo_result.getInt("page"));
            spidy_iTN_rootO.setLast_page(Jo_result.getInt("last_page"));
            spidy_iTN_rootO.setTotal(Jo_result.getInt("total"));
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray(Jo_result.getString("results"));

            for (int i = 0; i < spidy_iTN_rootO.getCount(); i++) {
                JSONObject resultsObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
                itemResults_api_constr spidy_iTN_resultsO = new itemResults_api_constr();

                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setData_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("data_id"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setName(resultsObject
                        .getString("name"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setRarity(resultsObject
                        .getInt("rarity"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setRestriction_level(resultsObject
                        .getInt("restriction_level"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setImg(resultsObject
                        .getString("img"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setType_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("type_id"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setSub_type_id(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sub_type_id"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setPrice_last_changed(resultsObject
                        .getString("price_last_changed"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setMax_offer_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("max_offer_unit_price"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setMin_sale_unit_price(resultsObject
                        .getInt("min_sale_unit_price"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setOffer_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_availability"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setSale_availability(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_availability"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setSale_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("sale_price_change_last_hour"));
                spidy_iTN_resultsO.setOffer_price_change_last_hour(resultsObject
                        .getInt("offer_price_change_last_hour"));
                spidy_iTN_rootO.addObject(spidy_iTN_resultsO);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return spidy_iTN_rootO;
    }

    public interface itemListToListings {
        public void itemListToListings(itemRoot_api_constr resultClass);
    }


}
```

And finally in my activity.java i can use my object in the method `itemListToListings()`.

How can I make this loop through all pages (`last_page` property) and add all JSON values as object in the same list.

EDIT: My `itemListToListings` function in my activity.

```
public void itemListToListings(final itemRoot_api_constr spidy_iTN_construct) {
            ArrayList<listItemWidgets_constr> image_details = getListData(spidy_iTN_construct);
            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            lv1.setAdapter(new itemListAdapter(this, image_details));
            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                    //listItemWidgets_constr newsData = (listItemWidgets_constr) lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(resultsActivity.this, "Selected :" + spidy_iTN_construct.results(position).name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(resultsActivity.this, listingsActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("itemId", spidy_iTN_construct.results(position).data_id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
```

EDIT 3: error log

```
05-01 07:17:39.828    3620-3620/com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile, PID: 3620
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile.AsyncTasks.itemsByInput_AsyncTask$itemListToListings.itemListToListings(com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile.constructors.itemRoot_api_constr)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile.AsyncTasks.itemsByInput_AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(itemsByInput_AsyncTask.java:88)
            at com.example.krijn.gw2TP_androidMobile.AsyncTasks.itemsByInput_AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(itemsByInput_AsyncTask.java:27)
```

After I get this error in the Logcat I still see the Log updating with the following in `doInBackground`

```
for (int n = 1; n < nPage; n++){
            Log.i("gw2Log", "n: " + n);
            publishProgress(JoToJO_constructor(spidyHttpGetRequest(makeUrl(n))));
        }
```

After that is done looping the application crashes.

Comment: Line 27 in `itemsByInput_AsyncTask` = `public class itemsByInput_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, itemRoot_api_constr, Void> {` and line 89 = `itemListToListings.itemListToListings(iacs[0]); }` in `onProgressUpdate()`

Comment: Have you done this itemsByInput_AsyncTask.setItemListToListings(this); ?

Comment: @inmyth I can't believe that I couldnt figure that out myself. While first testing your code I commented that as it returned an error (not sure why i did that) and never thought of moving it back. Anyway your provided code works flawlessly now, excellent thank you very much!

Comment: I added a final note in my answer to address another issue. Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to make chain calls depending on `last_page` property you get from the first page. I would do somethig like this where upon each completion of a request the UI is updated on `onProgressUpdate`

```
public class itemsByInput_AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, itemRoot_api_constr, Void> {

 JSONObject Jo_result;
 private itemListToListings itemListToListings;
 String userSearchRequest;

 public itemsByInput_AsyncTask(String userSearchRequest){
  this.userSearchRequest = userSearchRequest;
 } 

 private String makeUrl(int page){
    return "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/" + 
           this.userSearchRequest + "/" + page;
 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    itemRoot_api_constr iac;

    iac = JoToJO_constructor(spidyHttpGetRequest(makeUrl(0)));
    nPage = iac.getLast_page();
    publishProgress(iac);

    for (int n = 1; n<nPage; n++){
         publishProgress(spidyHttpGetRequest(makeUrl(n)));
    }
    return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(itemRoot_api_constr... iacs) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(iacs);
       // assuming method itemListToListings updates UI
       // if it doesn't then publishProgress and onProgressUpdate are not needed 
       // and itemListToListings can be done in doInBackground
       this.itemListToListings.itemListToListings(iacs[0]);
 }

  @Override
  protected Void onPostExecute(Void void) {
    super.onPostExecute(void);   
    // unused    
 }
}
```

Also:
Adapter, views, and related click listeners should be initiated once. You should move all variables inside of `itemListToListings` as your Activity field so everytime this callback is called, they won't need to be initiated again.

```
  ListView lv1;
  ArrayList<listItemWidgets_constr> image_details = new ArrayList<>();
  itemListAdapter adapter; 

  void onCreate(){
    ...
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new itemListAdapter(this, image_details);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(...);
  }

  public void itemListToListings(final itemRoot_api_constr spidy_iTN_construct) {
        image_details.clear();
        image_details.addAll(getListData(spidy_iTN_construct));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      
    }
```

Comment: After fiddling around a bit i solved some errors I was getting but I'm still stuck with `publishProgress(spidyHttpGetRequest(makeUrl(n)));` returning `itemRoot_api_constr can not be applied to JSONObject`

Comment: You need to check if your AsyncTask is now AsyncTask<Void, itemRoot_api_constr, Void> and all return values of its methods.

Comment: The error was that the loop in `doInbackground` never pointed to `JoToJO_constructor` but only to `spidyHttpGetRequest`. This is the correct code now `publishProgress(JoToJO_constructor(spidyHttpGetRequest(makeUrl(n))));` Sadly I'm now getting a NullPointerException before the `doInBackground` loop starts and when the loop is done the application crashes? You can see the error log and more in the Post under EDIT 2.

Comment: Thank you for your response and edits, Now sadly a different error, I replaced the previous error in my top post with the new one i now have